# Is `git commit --amend -C HEAD` the same as `git commit --amend --no-edit`?

Tags: git

It seems that both commands will do exactly the same thing which is adding some staged changes to the last commit without invoking the editor.

I'm just curious to know if there are any technical differences that I am not aware of.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionally, yes, they are the same: `-C` sets the "edit/no-edit" flag to the "no" position while choosing `HEAD` as the commit from which to take the initial message, while `--no-edit` sets the flag without setting the commit, which remains defaulted to `HEAD`.  Note that you can combine `--no-edit` with `-c` to achieve the same result as `-C`.

Comment: If that's the case `git commit --amend --no-edit` would involve 1 less keystroke: caps lock.